# Is there a way to specify sentry handled attribute in the AWS Lambda Package?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sentry, aws-serverless

Heyho, currently I'm developing a serverless application with AWS Lambda.
I wrote an error package for the Errors which can occur in my Application, all of them are extending the `BaseException` class which itself extends `Error`. For handling those custom errors I wrote a `CustomErrorHandler` class. Now the handler class has a method called `handle` which takes the error and does some stuff pretty much unrelated to the throw and catch logic it just does check if it's a custom error and if yes it returns a valid JSON as an error with some additions and formatting rules, else it throws the Error again as a fallback for unknown errors. Now I've got a global `Router` which handles all the `Controllers` and the routing. All of this works like a charm, but when the `Controller` throws a `BaseException` which is caught in the router and passed to the `CustomErrorHandler` where it checks whether it is a `BaseException` or not I'd like to let the custom ones be set as handled and the rest as unhandled, but my custom ones keep getting an unhandled tag even if I catch them in the handler and rethrow and recatch them so Sentry would have its try-catch logic.

So my question: is there any attribute I can set so it is forced to look like handled or unhandled, I already tried to set the "handled" tag myself it just gets overwritten.

My much-simplified code looks like this:

Router:

```
export default class Router {
    constructor(request)
    {
        this.request = request;
        //do sth
    }
    
    async route()
    {
        try {
            return new Controller().helloWorld(this.request); //Done by controller
        } catch(e) {
            return new CustomErrorHandler().handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

CustomErrorHandler:

```
export default class CustomErrorHandler {
    handle(error) {
        if(error instanceof BaseException) {
            Sentry.captureException(error);  //this should get with handled = true
            return error.render(); //Some formatting code
        }
        else {
            Sentry.captureException(error); //this should get with handled = false
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
export default class Controller {
    helloWorld(request) {
        //do sth
        throw new BaseException();
    }
}
```

index.mjs (Lambda with node 18 needs index.mjs):

```
import {AWSLambda as SentryLambda} from "@sentry/serverless";

SentryLambda.init({
    dsn:                process.env.SENTRY_DSN,
    environment:        process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
    tracesSampleRate:   1.0,
});

export const handler = SentryLambda.wrapHandler(async(request, context) => {
    let router = new Router(request);

    return await router.route();
});
```